# Unable to scrape data after a dropdown

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from typing import Text, final
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-cases.html").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

states = soup.find("tbody", class_="children").find_all("tr")

# print(state.prettify())

for state in states:
# determining the name of the state
    name = state.a.text
    final_name = ""
    for character in name:
        if character in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM ":
            final_name += character

    print(final_name)

    # finding the daily number of cases on average
    try:
        daily_cases_avg = state.find("td",class_="bignum cases show-mobile").text
    except Exception as e:
        daily_cases_avg = None
    print(daily_cases_avg)

    # finding the number of cases per 100,000
    try:
        num_cases_per_hunThous = state.find("td",class_="num cases show-mobile").text
    except Exception as e:
        num_cases_per_hunThous = None
    print(num_cases_per_hunThous)

    # finding percent change over the past 14 days
    try:
        pct_change_cases_14 = state.find("td",class_="chart cases wider td-end show-mobile").span.text
    except Exception as e:
        pct_change_cases_14 = None
    print(pct_change_cases_14)

    # daily average of the number of people hospitalized
    try:
        daliy_hos_avg = state.find_all("td",class_="bignum")[1].text
    except Exception as e:
        daily_hos_avg = None
    print(daliy_hos_avg)

    # number of people people hospitalized per 100,000
    try:
        num_hos_hunThous = state.find_all("td",class_="num")[1].text
    except Exception as e:
        num_hos_hunThous = None
    print(num_hos_hunThous)

    # percent change of number of hospitalized people over the past 14 days
    try:
        pct_change_hos_14 = state.find("td",class_="num td-end").text
    except Exception as e:
        pct_change_hos_14 = None
    print(pct_change_hos_14)

    # daily average of deaths
    try:
        daily_death_avg = state.find_all("td",class_="bignum")[2].text
    except Exception as e:
        daily_death_avg = None
    print(daily_death_avg)

    # number of deaths per 100,000
    try:
        deaths_hunThous = state.find_all("td",class_="num td-end")[1].text
    except Exception as e:
        deaths_hunThous = None
    print(deaths_hunThous)

    # percent of people fully vaccinated
    try:
        pct_vac = state.find("td",class_="num vax td-end").text
    except Exception as e:
        pct_vac = None
    print(pct_vac)
```

All I am trying to do is scrape COVID-19 data off of the New York Times. I am a beginner so I am just using this as a way to learn how to scrape websites efficiently. However, the website only the states that show up prior to a dropdown.
On the website, after the state of Illinois, there is button "Show all." The states that appear after clicking that button are not getting scraped for data, so I was wondering how I can get past that to get data for all of the states.

Answer (score 0):

If you open developer tools and go to network you can see all of the requests the page is sending. I found one request it sends [https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/coronavirus-tracking/data/counties.json](https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/coronavirus-tracking/data/counties.jsonhttps://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/coronavirus-tracking/data/counties.json)

The website recieves a link for every county. Each element in the json obj contains a link to another nyt article that contains the avg cases for that individual county.

It would be more complicated but you could write a script that goes through each of these countys and scrapes the data. Then add up the avg cases for each state based on each individual county.

That is what I would do